# Can I log Mysql database login attempts?

Tags: mysql, linux, logging

on a Linux Ubuntu server, under

```
/var/log
and 
/var/log/mysql
```

I can find Mysql log files, but all of them are empty despite I have used the database. I have phpMyAdmin installed as well. Is it possible to see when and which ip address has tried to login to the database?

Comment: have you tried looking at the binary log on phpmyadmin?

Comment: Just checked /status/binary log in phpMyAdmin and could not find anything useful there. But I suppose this is the the only place the login attempts should be in, if they would exist anywhere.

Comment: This link will help you. [read this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33654/mysql-logging-activity-from-specific-user-or-ip)

Comment: Please refer to this link may be useful http://serverfault.com/questions/65255/log-mysql-login-attempts